# Editing existing file in Android

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I am trying to edit existing file on the device by-First- select the file using selector that retrieve the path of the file like this "mnt/sdcard/file.png". Then I pass it to reader to read the existing file then modify it by by shifting the Ascii of every char. Then Overwrite it again to replace the old one.

I have tested the code on a desktop app on PC files and it Works perfect, but does not work as an Android app. It worked on my device once but did not work again

About what I did:

1)Add writing on External source Permission in the Mainafest file
2)Select the file right and retrieve it path
3)Read the file content true

```
        File file = f;
        FileInputStream fin;
        fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fin.read(fileContent);
```

4)Modify the file bytes
5)Write back (Overwrite) in the original file

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
        fos.write(enc_msg);
        fos.write((byte)seed);
        fin.close();
        fos.close();
```

6)Set the file to null again
7)Call finish() in the onClickListner

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @FoamyGuy .. It does not throw any exception, but the file is not modified although when I check file Details, I found out that the modification date was upgraded to the execution time.

Comment: Why don't you log all the exceptions in your catch blocks and post the logcat in your querstion?

Comment: try closing your file input stream before you make your file output stream.

Comment: @PradeepPati .. I have already did this and did not catch any exception

Comment: @FoamyGuy .. Do you think Closing the input stream may differ from Desktop app to Android app!!?

Comment: Is your method getting called?

Comment: @PradeepPati .. I have checked that all my code run line by line

Comment: Try closing the `fin` before doing `fos.write()`

Comment: Are you connecting your phone to PC via USB when your app runs? That might be the issue

Comment: I tried both ways and I will try again now @PradeepPati

Comment: Actually, my file is into folder called SDcard in the root not physical Card @323go

Comment: @Rinkalkumar .. It is useful, but did not solve the problem. Your code working perfect on a desktop application, but does not work on the Android device. I have voted you up appreciating your help

Comment: what exactly you are facing problem on android device

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer

Comment: @Rinkalkumar .. I have looked at your answer. I have found the solution for my problem by using a liberary Common-io that handle every procedure using files like I mentioned down. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Given how little code you've pasted to your question it is obvious to me that you haven't read the documentation about [Saving Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of work, I have reached the final solution by:

1)Using Common-io library
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

2)Writing this simple line only after import common-io

```
  FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()), myByteArray, false);
```

the last attribute (Fasle) for overriding the file .. Append flag

Answer (score 1):

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

However, the device must be disconnected from USB. Otherwise you need to unplug and replug the device to see the changes.

Comment: After you close the output stream. And this is because of changes implemented in HC and later version, File access via MTP instead of Mass storage. Which means your MTP should know something changed in order to refresh the data.

Comment: should ""file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" is equivlant to my file path ? I know that we use "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" in case of getting file from SDCard..what about getting from the root?

Comment: What we need to understand here is that we are sending a broadcast that an external media is mounted, and your file isn't the media, the SD card is. The MTP program will receive this broadcast and refresh its cache, probably along with other programs who receive this broadcast.